# Response [400] error while sending a text file to a url using python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am writing a small code in python to send a text file (request) over a URL

```
import requests
def send_file():
    URL = 'https://www.manhattan-tool.com'
    file_name='/myfile_path/testing.txt'
    files={'testing.txt': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    r=requests.post(URL, files=files)
    print r
```

It throws some `<Response [400]>` error. Can anyone tell me how can I send a text file to a url?

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked for me.

Comment: @ Tushar Makkar, i don't understand but it is not functioning in my environment. Actually i have to send a request to url which in response will create a folder over a remote FTP server consisting some information which i have send via text file. My text file has some items which I am asking via url to generate some information based upon such items  and I suppose to see a folder over ftp server.

Comment: I found a solution, I can see a folder with requested list over a url.